# mongodb filtered result grouping

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a mongo-backed contact database in rails. I am doing reports that reports multiple checkbox using a filter.

For example:

1. I am using checkbox filter
2. Table name is `Conversion`
3. Columns in `Conversion` table are:  `browser`, `date`, `city`, `state`, `country`, `network`, `language`
4. I am selecting `date`, `city` for filter, after filtering grouping should occur, based on the filter
5. Note: first filter next only grouping
6. Sometimes: `date`, `city`, `country` for filter, it will depends on the user

I have done this code only

```
Conversion.collection.aggregate([
   { "$match" => {
     "date" => { '$gte' => start_date, '$lte' => end_date }
     }
   },
   { "$group" => {
     "_id" => {
       "country" => "$country",
       "city" => "$city",
       "browser" => "$browser",
       "network" => "$network",
        "language" => "$language"
      }
    }
  },
])
```

But this code is grouping all columns every time. I want the checkbox selected column only grouping to occur. For that how do I write the grouping code? Can anyone suggest any idea?

Comment: First create an object based on the checkbox-selected columns, e.g. grouping = {}. if(...) { grouping.country = "$country"; } ... and then use this object in your group step: {$group => { "_id" => grouping } }